# android. Starting activity from url doesn't work from browser but works from text editor

Tags: android

I want to start my `Activity` when user clicks on URL from browser. I created customized my manifest this way:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".views.RestorePwActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data
                android:host="mysite.com"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

`Activity` opens when I click `URL` from notes or any text editor, but when I click `URL` in browser it redirects me to a website.

I saw similar questions on stack-overflow but none of that answers helps.
I also read opinions that modern browsers restrict such behavior. I'm using Android 5+. Is it possible to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deep link sample code:

Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="splus.in.codestructure">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
                <data android:scheme="example"
                    android:host="deeplinksample" />
                <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_two);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Uri data = intent.getData();

    }
}
```

You can execute in two ways:

Command Line:

```
F:\AndroidStudioSetup\sdk\platform-tools> adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "example://deeplinksample" splus.in.codestructure
```

Output on console:

```
 Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=example://deeplinksample pkg=splus.in.codestructure }
        Status: ok
        Activity: splus.in.codestructure/.HomeActivity
        ThisTime: 90
        TotalTime: 10383
        WaitTime: 108
        Complete
```

If you want to open from Browser then try below code:

Deeplinking.html

[image]

May you keep this file on server or you can copy on your SD card & open with browser, then click on **Deep link Sample. It will open your app.

Let me know know if require more help!

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. So, 1. I did the same that you suggested before, and when I run adb command I see a dialog with my app, thats ok. 2. when I click URL in browser the dialog doesn't appear and it redirects me to the website. 3. I changed scheme from https to example and it works! It's great! But I need to open my app by clicking https scheme. Do you have any idea why https scheme doesn't work?

Comment: I have tried with data & it's work 
  <data android:scheme="https" android:host="mysite.com" />
  <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.mysite.com" />
  
  While I run html page it's ask me to open with like browser/our application etc...

Comment: I configured intent filter this way:             <intent-filter>
                <action ... MAIN" />
                <action ... etc>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="deeplinksample" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="deeplinksample.com" />
                <data android:scheme="example" android:host="deeplinksample" />
            </intent-filter>
And only example://deeplinksample url redirects me to my app.
https://deeplinksample.com doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer original document of Android for deep link https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html

As your code seem fine in manifest but I can't compile it. If you want code help share your project.

I hope given link will helpful!